# How can I optimize my multiprocessing in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to run multiProcessing in python for the first time but when I debug in PyCharm I see that Thread 8 is waiting for a lock and I believe this is where my code is slowing down. I thought about mapping process pool in the while loop but this seems redundant to do this. Am i on the right track with this?

```
import random
import time
import math
import multiprocessing as mp  # alias

# from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

# initial sequence:
# HHTHTHHHTHHHTHTH

coinChoices = ["H", "T"]  # choices
idealFlip = "HHTHTHHH"    # string to match
flip = ""                 # resets flip

margin_error = 0.1  # accuracy
num_matches = 0.0   # matched strings
probability = 0     # calc. probability
counter = 0         # iterations
flag = 1            # exit token
secondFlag = 1

check = math.ceil(pow(2, len(idealFlip))/2)  # used for printing prob

# flips a coin  *NOT USED*
def flip_coin(coins):
    return str(random.choice(coins))


# requests (num) tasks to be completed
def flip_coin_num(num):
    return str(random.choice(coinChoices))


# theoretical probability
def compute_probability():
    size = len(idealFlip)
    return math.pow(0.5, size)


# actual probability
def empirical_probability(count, num_flips):
    return count / num_flips


# TODO: implement multiprocessing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # print("# cores: %d" % mp.cpu_count())

    probability = compute_probability()
    print("\nInitial probability of landing on the sequence: " + str(probability) + "\n")

    actualProb = 0
    empiricalProb = 0

    tasks = range(len(idealFlip))
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)


    while flag != 0 or counter == 1000:

        temp = pool.map(flip_coin_num, tasks)


        # add other processes?
        # handles close / join


        flip = "".join(temp)
        # print(temp)
        # print(flip)

        if counter != 0:
            empiricalProb = empirical_probability(num_matches, counter)
        if flip == idealFlip:
            num_matches += 1

        counter += 1
        flip = ""

        if counter % check is 0:
            print("Probability" + str(empricalProb))
```

[image: Tracking of threads]

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't this related to the GIL? When the process returns its results it's waiting for the GIL to be obtained. It may also be related to the results being pickled which may take some time depending on the size of the return object.

Comment: @GlobalTraveler I just did some research on GIL and I didn't even know that existed lol. I will go back and see If that is the root of my problem.

Comment: No problem. My hunch says it is trying to collect the results. Essentially the multiprocess object spawns N independent python processes on your different cores. The information is pickled and distributed. I am assuming the last part is what is causing the 'delay'. The GIL is considered a problem for some but also gives it python its great single core performance. There are attempts to get rid of the GIL (see jython, pypi etc). However these have their advantages / disadvantages.